# Clearing the form fields and saving the details in angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have created a simple form using angular js. When the user enter their details and submit it the values will be saved in console, but the values remains in the field even after clicking the submit button. 
I want to save details of various fields in console for now and need to clear the fields once the submit button is clicked so that the next person details can be entered. all the user details will be saved in console for now so that we can retrive it later

View code:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="person_info">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Person info</title>
<script src="../angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller_class2.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="info">
<div class="forms">
  Name: <input type="text" value="name" ng-model="person.name"> </br></br>
  First Name : <input type="text" value="fname" ng-model="person.firstname"></br></br>
  Phone Number : <input type="text"  value="number" ng-model="person.number"></br></br>
  Email : <input type="email" value="email" ng-model="person.email"></br></br>
  Address : <input type="text" value="address" ng-model="person.address"></br></br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" ng-click="test()">
</div>

  <p>Name : {{person.name}}</p>
<p>{{person.firstname}}</p>
  <p>{{person.number}}</p>
    <p>{{person.email}}</p>
      <p>{{person.address}}</p>

  {{ person | json }}
```

Controller code :

```
var person_info = angular.module('person_info', []);
person_info.controller('info', function($scope) {
$scope.test = function () {
console.log($scope.person);
}
});
```

Comment: Details will be available in `$scope.person` object

Comment: how should i write it in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/mpZqqWcDd8hekmdeQh0W?p=preview) of your code...

you should use `ng-click` instead `onClick`...

Comment: I would suggest you to warp fields in `form` and then use `ng-submit`

Answer (score 1):

You could set a property on the model to the saved person and reference this object underneath the form:

Controller:

```
$scope.test = function(){

    // do whatever needs to be done to save the person

    $scope.savedPerson = $scope.person;
}
```

View:

```
<p>Saved person {{savedPerson.name}}</p>
```